# Determine if the user added a Custom Keyboard to the keyboards list. iOS 8, Extension

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

Is there any way to determine from the containing app if the user added a custom keyboard to the keyboards list.

For example, this approach uses the Fleksy and Swype apps. 
When the app opened from a background it knows whether the keyboard added to the list or not.

I looked through all the documentation about the app extension and custom keyboards, but I didn't find any solution of that.

I would appreciate if someone could point me to right direction.

Comment: Answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211422/how-to-check-programatically-what-international-keyboards-are-installed-on-iphon/8211617#8211617

Comment: I find answer in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211422/how-to-check-programatically-what-international-keyboards-are-installed-on-iphon/8211617#8211617

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() as a Dictionary.
Inside you can find "AppleKeyboards" as an array with all the apple id's of the installed keyboards.

Enjoy

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

When the keyboard loads, write a boolean to your shared container's user defaults.

When the containing app loads, read that value.

Comment: Yes. That's right, it will work. But how to determine when the user just added a keyboard but no once opened it. That's the question. The fleksy and the swipe work in that way.

Comment: I think in the private API there are such notification via Notification Center, may be Flesky and Swipe received the Apple's permission to use it.